# Why does accessing an instance attribute in tkinter require brackets, while accessing an instance attribute in pygame require dot?

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

In `pygame`, I use `games.screen.width` to access the `width` attribute.

```
won_message = games.Message(value = "You won!",
                            size = 100,
                            color = color.red,
                            x = games.screen.width/2,
                            y = games.screen.height/2,
                            lifetime = 250,
                            after_death = games.screen.quit)
```

In `tkinter` I use `self.result['text']` to access the `text` attribute

```
self.result = Label(self, text='Result:?')                            
self.result.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=W) 
self.result['text'] = 'Finish'
```

Can anyone explain to me why there are different ways to access attributes?

Comment: they have different method because different people create it and they choose different method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tkinter, these attributes aren't attributes of the object, they are attributes of the underlying tk widget for which the Tkinter class is merely a wrapper.

The canonical way to access these attributes is with the `configure` or `cget` methods. Tkinter provides a dict-like interface simply as a syntactic shorthand.

For example, the following two statements are identical:

```
self.result.configure(text="Finish")
self.result["text"] = "Finish"
```

as are these:

```
print(self.result.cget("text"))
print(self.result["text"])
```